# UPDATE IGNORE with function LOWER() in WHERE-clause does nothing

Tags: mysql, sql, function, case-sensitive

I have a very small table `discs` like this

```
did freedbdiscid    aname           dtitle                          genre   year    tracks
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   4010755600  Man on an Island    A New Day - Live in Las Vegas   Pop     2004    16
1   4010755600  MAN ON AN ISLAND    A New Day - Live in Las Vegas   Pop     2004    16
```

which I'd like to change using

`UPDATE IGNORE discs SET aname = 'Man on an Island' WHERE LOWER(aname) LIKE 'man on an island';`

which changes ... **nothing**!

I expected at least a warning or two duplicate entries for there should be no uppercase-title any more. It seems the `WHERE`-clause in the `UPDATE` does not match second row which can not be – to me. Is there something you do see? I've got no idea of what's going on here ...island';

Comment: "I expected at least a warning" Remove the `IGNORE` keyword from the query.

Answer (score 0):

`IGNORE` - clumsy me, works fine without!